# Why is Collections.sort() optimised for LinkedList, but is not optimised for ArrayList?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, timsort

Why does `Collections.sort()` creates an extra object array and performs Tim sort on the array and then finally copies the sorted array back into `List` object? I know this call is optimized for `LinkedList`, but won't we lose out on performance for `ArrayList`?

We could have avoided `2n` number of operations in converting it into an object array and adding them back to the list. I know that these extra operations wouldn't affect the Big-O of the whole sorting operation, but I believe it could've been further optimised for `ArrayList`.

Am I missing something here? I'm just trying to understand why the architecture is laid out as such. Thanks.

https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/Collections.java#l164

Comment: Please PM here if the question is a possible duplicate. I will be glad to know that there is already an answer to this question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are looking at an older JDK version. At least since since JDK 1.8.0_162 `Collections.sort()` calls `List`'s `sort(Comparator<? super E> c)`. And while the default implementation creates an array from the `List` and sorts that array, `ArrayList` overrides that default implementation, and sorts the backing array directly.

`Collections`'s `sort`:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list) {
    list.sort(null);
}
```

`List`'s `sort`:

```
default void sort(Comparator<? super E> c) {
    Object[] a = this.toArray();
    Arrays.sort(a, (Comparator) c);
    ListIterator<E> i = this.listIterator();
    for (Object e : a) {
        i.next();
        i.set((E) e);
    }
}
```

`ArrayList`'s `sort`:

```
public void sort(Comparator<? super E> c) {
    final int expectedModCount = modCount;
    Arrays.sort((E[]) elementData, 0, size, c);
    if (modCount != expectedModCount) {
        throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
    }
    modCount++;
}
```

In other words, this has been addressed in JDK versions newer than the one you are looking at.

You can look at the source [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/c00bdbbd9a77/src/share/classes/java/util/Collections.java#l140) (thanks to eckes's link).

Comment: The link to the source file (supposedly for JDK8, though I don't fully understand the repo's organization) does show `Collections.sort` using the default `List.sort` implementation directly.

Comment: Not what I see; I see sorting done on the `toArray()` on line 230 (perhaps you're looking at the synchronized wrapper?).  That said, OpenJDK11 is showing what you're saying in its source.

Comment: @Slaw the linked source file seems to be jdk8-b132. My answer contains code of JDK 1.8.0_162

Comment: Here's the JDK9 version - http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/file/d966fc5a7be5/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Collections.java. I'll link to JDK 1.8.0_162 if I can find it

Comment: @Eran http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/c00bdbbd9a77/src/share/classes/java/util/Collections.java#l141